# using Membrane keypad to answer math prob. Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying my first project in Arduino.
I am trying to use my Membrane Switch Module to answer simple math prob. like 1+1.
in general, I am trying to make my Arduino do the following:

ask for an answer to 1+1
if the answer is correct turn the light on for 30 sec
else blink 3 times
and ask again...

the result for my code is that it is running endlessly without getting the input of the keypad.

thank you for the help.

I am new to Arduino and for c++ coding :)

```
#include <Keypad.h>
char pad[4][4]={
  {1,2,3,'A'},
  {4,5,6,'B'},
  {7,8,9,'C'},
  {'*',0,'#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[4]={9,8,7,6};
byte colPins[4]={5,4,3,2};

Keypad customKeypad=Keypad (makeKeymap(pad),rowPins,colPins,4,4);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("how much is 1+1?");
  char answer=customKeypad.getKey();
  Serial.println(answer);
  delay(10000);
  if (answer==2){
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    delay(1000);}
    else {
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad/

`getKey` returns the currently pressed key, as you wait 10 seconds between calls to `getKey` it's likely that you'll miss your key presses unless you hold the key down. You should use `waitForKey` instead.